# filter array in props

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, next.js

i keep having a problem with filtering an array of objects in props in a nextjs page. i m using below json and coding.

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name1",
    "category": ["food"]
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "name2",
    "category": ["food", "beverages"]
}]
```

```
import React from "react";

const test2 = ({ prods }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {prods
                    .filter((product) => product.category.includes("eve"))
                    .map((filterarray) => (
                        <li>
                            {filterarray.id}
                            {filterarray.name}
                            {filterarray.category}
                        </li>
                    ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const prods = (await import("./product.json")).default;
    return {
        props: {
            prods,
        },
    };
}
export default test2;
```

listing the full array works. (data comes as 1 string eg 'foodbeverage' but that should still be ok i think)
Filtering on id works fine. But when i try to use include it no longer displays any result.
if anyone could point me to what i m doing wrong. or if i better follow a different approach, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `include` with `some` on the `category` array:

```js
let prods = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "name1",
    category: ["food"]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "name2",
    category: ["food", "beverages"]
  }
];

let result = prods.filter((product) =>
  product.category.some((pro) => pro.includes("eve"))
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array#includes()` does not do partial matches. You need to use `String#includes()` on each element in the array.

You could do this by using `Array#some()` in the filter.

```
prods.filter((product) => product.category.some(cat=>cat.includes("eve")))
```